# Show matched lines for a given regex at Linux

Tags: linux, regex, grep, tail

I use that notation at my log files:

[something-something]

somethings are necessary and variable length characters and numbers. My special log file includes line that has characters explained above. I.e.

```
Line 1: DEBUG [AS-kmksdf] Error occured!
Line 2: something somethingg..
```

I want to get Line 1. My log files grows dynamically and I show it at my screen with:

```
tail -f log.txt
```

How can I show just that special lines?

I know that I will use grep and my regex will be sth. like

```
[[A-Z]*-[A-Z]*]
```

how to combine them with that command. This doesn't work:

```
tail -f log.txt | grep [[A-Z]*-[A-Z]*]
```

I use cygwin with windows7 and can run some linux commands on my cmd.exe.

Comment: Look at `grep`.

Comment: Your edit made this a completely different question, and it is still not precisely described what you actually want. No developer with experience is willing to work towards such "requirements"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your regular expression:

- First of all, I'd advice you to always use the `-P` switch, which enables [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions).

  By default, `grep` uses [Basic regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_regular_expression), which aren't used widely and suffer from inconsistent espacing.
- As is `[A-Z]`, brackets have special meaning in regular expressions. To use a literal bracket in PCREs, escape it with a backslash: `\[` or `\]`
- Regular expressions are case sensitive, unless you set the `-i` switch.
- `*` means *any* number of occurrences, including (`0`). You might want to use `+` instead (any *positive* number of occurrences).
- **Always** surround your regular expression with double quotes, or the bash will expand characters.

As a result, the following command will work:

```
tail -f log.txt | grep -Pi "\[[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+\]"
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I realized another issue for me.

Comment: @kamaci: Your edit requires a completely different approach, so it's an entirely different question. Instead of editing it, it's preferable to ask a new question.

Comment: Oops my grep command has no -P option. Maybe because of cygwin.

Comment: That's probably a bug. You could either install `pcregrep` or use @crizot's approach.

Comment: I have rollbacked my question and new question is: http://superuser.com/questions/439249/show-starting-with-a-special-line-until-a-special-line-regex-for-linux-tail-comm

Answer (score 1):

```
tail -f log.txt |grep -E '\[[a-zA-Z]*-[a-zA-Z]*\]'
```

You can use [Regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) to test your regex expressions. Also you should use `-E` on `grep`. It is not mandatory, and not necessary in this case, but allow you to use extended regex expressions.

Comment: *Recursive*? Why?

Comment: Sory. I edit my answer, it is `-E`. It is not mandatory but I use `-E` as a rule because usualy I work with extended regex expressions. In this case it is not necessary.

Comment: that's nice. How about getting all the lines started with that special line until a line starts with number,number and : as like 14:  ?

Comment: You're right Dennis. I fixed my answer. Thanks

Comment: @Kamaci I don't think what you want is possible with just regex. You will need something like [Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/).