# Show starting with a special line until a special line regex for Linux tail command

Tags: linux, regex, grep, tail

I use that notation at my log files:

[something-something]

somethings are necessary and variable length characters and numbers. My special log file includes line that has characters explained above. i.e.

```
Line 1: 14:40:45,107 DEBUG [AS-kmksdf] Error occured!
Line 2: something somethingg..
Line 3: 14:40:45,108 DEBUG Some other errors
```

I want to get Line 1 and Line 2(because error continues at line 2). My log files grows dynamically and I show it at my screen with:

```
tail -f log.txt
```

How can I show the lines that begins with my special line until it gets a new line that has number number : number number : number number , one or more length number (this is hour and comma seperated error code number)

(I think looking for number,number: may be enough)

I use cygwin with windows7 and can run some linux commands on my cmd.exe.

This question is releted to: [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/439229/show-matched-lines-for-a-given-regex-at-linux)

Answer (score 1):

#### Command

```
tail -f log.txt | awk '{if($1~/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9],[0-9]+/){if($0~/\[[A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+\]/){MATCH=1}else{MATCH=0}}if(MATCH){print $0}}'
```

#### How it works

- `awk` processes the piped output line by line.
- If the first field of the line (delimited by space and denoted by `$1`) matches the regular expression `[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9],[0-9]+`, the value of `MATCH` gets changed:

  - If the pattern `\[[A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+\]` occurs, `MATCH` gets set to `1` (truthy).
  - If the pattern `\[[A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+\]` does not occur, `MATCH` gets set to `0` (falsy).
- Finally, if `MATCH` is truthy, `print $0` prints the entire line (denoted by `$0`).

  Since `MATCH` is truthy if and only if the last line starting with a time stamp contained the pattern `[something-something]`, this yields the desired output.